# How to combine multiple IIF statements in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, case, iif

I'm trying to combine the following IIF statement in SQL Server in a Select statement. How would I go about this?

```
IIF(CLMD_TYPE2 = TYPE, ID_ID2, NULL),      
IIF(CLMD_TYPE3 = TYPE, ID_ID2, NULL),
IIF(CLMD_TYPE4 = TYPE, ID_ID2, NULL),
IIF(CLMD_TYPE5 = TYPE, ID_ID2, NULL),
IIF(CLMD_TYPE6 = TYPE, ID_ID2, NULL),
IIF(CLMD_TYPE7 = TYPE, ID_ID2, NULL),
IIF(CLMD_TYPE8 = TYPE, ID_ID2, NULL) AS DIAG_CD
```

Answer (score 1):

use an `in`:

```
IIF(type IN (clmd_type1, clmd_type2, ..., clmd_type6), id_id2, null)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `CASE` statement:

```
case 
   when type IN (clmd_type1, clmd_type2, clmd_type3, clmd_type4, clmd_type5, clmd_type6) 
      then id_id2
end
```